# Any way to sort listed files in ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-file

Is there is any way to sort (Alphabetically/ datewise/ type) files that are received  from `listFiles()`.

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
try {
if (files.length == 0)
    return null;

    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        {
            String st=files[i].getName();

            MyFiles.add(st);}
    }

    return MyFiles;

}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); return null;}}
```